# How to track the copy activity using job control file or 0 kb files(fin) in ADF?

Tags: azure, android-activity, copy, azure-data-factory, job-control

As i am new to ADF,need help on below scenario.I need to copy the files
azure blob to SFTP.The files are as below:

XYZ0034_20210320.csv
XYZ0034_20210321.csv
XYZ0034_20210322.csv

On coping these files to SFTP,to track the copy,
need to create fin file or need to job control
file/table at end of the copying activity.

for example:
XYZ0034_202103200030.csv
XYZ0034_202103200045.csv
XYZ0034_202103200100.csv

Requirement:

XYZ0034_202103200030.csv
XYZ0034_202103200030.fin

JOB Control:

XYZ0034_202103200030.csv Y
XYZ0034_202103200045.csv Y
XYZ0034_202103200100.csv N after copying to Y

Comment: For example, you have 3 files in blob, actually, from blob to SFTP, output is .fin files? Please clairfy your question, it's really hard to understand.

Comment: To confirm that the file is copied already, need to generate 0KB file with either  extension (<filename>.fin or <filename>.ctl ) at end of the copy activity. This is my requirement

Comment: Hey @SathishkumarGovindasamy,
so your requirement is to 1st copy the files as is from SFTP to Blob and then create 0kb files with the same name and .fin extension?
So in case if SFTP has 3 files after your ADF job, your blob would contain 6 files

Comment: yes..nandan. you are correct

Comment: @SathishkumarGovindasamy per my experience, data factory can't create two files in one sink or create the empty files. Only if the source is empty. It can split copy the file to sink but can't be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more diable using Azure automation runbook. You can use webhook activity in ADF to call this notebook which will do the following -

1. Use a web hook to invoke this notebook
2. The runbook creates a file on this SFTP